# Воспроизведение музыки с онлайн радио

Tags: java, streaming, online, radio

Хочу написать код, который обращается к радиостанции и выбирает нужную радиостанцию, затем запускает её воспроизведение на ПК, как это сделать на java, вообще не знаю, куда двигаться.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать библиотеку [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html)

Тогда код для консольного плеера будет примерно таким -

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
InputStream fin = url.openStream();
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(fin);

Player player;
player = new Player(is);
player.play();
```

Может есть и более продвинутые библиотеки для воспроизведения потокового аудио. Это первое, что нашлось.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, вот мой код. 
http://pastebin.com/9dvE048B 
Он запускается без ошибок, но воспроизведение музыки на пк не начинается.

Comment: Импорты покажи еще. Может библиотеку криво добавил?

Comment: import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

Импорты, а подтянул maven'ом

Comment: <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlayer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-1</version>

Comment: Проверил только что ваш код. У меня работает отлично.

Comment: у меня вин 10 а у вас?

Comment: пробовал на 10 и на 7

Comment: т.е. вы запустили мой код с pastebin и у вас всё работало? Мог бы прислать свой профиль вк/скайп для связи?

Comment: koba_andrew - skp